# Node.js if I have a number of call back functions which is the most efficient way to stack them

Tags: node.js

Using async waterfall Or using the .then(function) stacked after one another which pretty much does the same thing. Right now I have come across these two way of writing functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/tj/co . 
It uses promises to write non-blocking code in a better way .
eg.

```
co(function* () {
  var result = yield Promise.resolve(true);
  return result;
}).then(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
}, function (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

could use async.waterfall (only use it if you need order of the functions to be executed as well as the result/output of one function to be passed over the next one) , otherwise I would use either async.parallel or async.series

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient.. in what aspect? Easy to maintain? Fast?

In my experience, it is not worth it to focus on speed for these kinds of things. Even if one is 100% faster than the other, any speed increase will most likely be orders of magnitude less than network latency.

Pick the one that you think is easiest to understand/maintain. If you end up with code that runs too slowly, benchmark it to find the slowest parts and improve those.